# Discord(rewrite) Python - Roles and case sensitivity

Tags: python, url-rewriting, discord

```
      async def addrole(self, ctx, username: discord.Member, *, role):
            member = username
            rolename = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role)
            await member.add_roles(rolename)
            await ctx.send(f"Successfully added {member} to {rolename}")
```

I have been trying to make a simple command to add a user to a role in a discord server. The problem I am trying to solve is the issue of case sensitivity.

I have searched for an answer to this, and I have added case_insensitive=True to my bot = commands.etc. etc.) but that doesn't seem to work for this - I have then tried to use .lower() but I am still unable to add a user to the role unless case matches.

If rolename = Regular Member
I'd like to be able to use .addrole user RegULAR MeMBER - etc. regardless of case style.

The alternative method I tried to do was loop through all roles but this did not work either as I can't iterate r as lower. My last thought was to use the for loop, convert each occurrence to a dict and use lower. Which this I believe would probably work, but I have to imagine there is a more efficient way.

```
for r ctx.guild.roles
      if r.lower() == role.lower()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create out of the `ctx.guild.roles` a dictionary with the lowered as key and the original name as value.

```py
def convert_role(roles, role):
  roles_dict = {}
  for discord_role in roles:
    roles_dict[discord_role.lower()] = discord_role
  return roles_dict[role.lower()]
```

After use the function in your main function

```py
async def add_role(self, ctx, username: discord.Member, *, role):
  member = username
  role_name = convert_role(roles=ctx.guild.roles, role=role)
  await member.add_roles(role_name)
  await ctx.send(f"Successfully added {member} to {role_name }")
```

P.S.: Prefer make the name of your function easier readable by changing `addrole` into `add_role`